# ElementNotInteractableException using Selenium

Tags: selenium, automation, selenium-chromedriver

My web page has a button called "Attach file".
I am trying to upload a file but getting ElementNotInteractableException .
When I try to click on the button, I am able to, but while trying to upload the document I get the error.

Element that I am accessing

Attach File

How I am accessing

```
String filePath = "Users/am/Documents/test.pdf"

WebElement element = driver.get().findElement(locator);
            element.sendKeys(filePath);
```

Comment: Use the full absolute path for file path and what html element is it.

Comment: <div class="link-text"> Attach File</div>   
This is the HTML for the button

Comment: Sendkeys only works for input tags.

Comment: Try looking into Autoit.

Comment: @ArundeepChohan "Sendkeys only works for input tags."
Do you know any alternate solution for this ?

Comment: There will be an INPUT storing the path to the file to be uploaded. It may not be clickable but if you search the HTML you will find it.

Comment: <input multiple="multiple" class="hidden" type="file" name="abc_file[attachments][]" id="abc_file_attachments">
I found this, But when I tried to sendkeys the path via  this element's xpath, I get a different error.
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException : file not found at so and so path
@JeffC

Comment: Then something about the path you are sending is not correct.